# Why does a flight from Melbourne to Cape Town need to go via Doha?

Tags: air-travel, connecting-flights

Looking at tickets for, say, a flight from Melbourne (MEL) to Cape Town (CPT) I found none without an airport stop - i.e. at Doha (DOH).

I understand that the "direct" route (great circle) is perhaps too close to the southern pole, but what is the reason to make such a long route?

The ideal paths are:

```
MEL-DOH = 7,426 mi
DOH-CPT = 4,615 mi
------------------
TOTAL   = 12,041 mi
```

while the direct route is:

```
MEL-CPT = 6,416 mi
```

The half of the distance! Even if you don't follow the great circle (for the reason above) the "single hop" route will be very close to the first part of the trip (MEL-DOH).

A second thought might be about the lands below: of course MEL-DOH-CPT is for most of the path above lands. But as I learn [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16224/which-is-longest-oceanic-crossing-for-any-commercial-flight-route) it is not unusual to have long paths over the seas.

So, what are the reasons to avoid the shortest path in this example?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's not just a stop, it's a change (picking a random date a couple of week in the future you'd be in Doha for about 23 hours).  This is how airlines operate - they serve multiple routes form one or more bases or hubs (at which maintenance and many other services may be concentrated).  In Qatar's case their base is Doha.  So they fly from Doha to anywhere they can make a profit, e.g. MEL and CPT (other airlines use Hong Kong or Dubai for this connection).

Qantas use Melbourne as a base, so it wouldn't be too hard for them to fly to Cape Town - or for South African Airways to do the same (Cape Town is a hub for them).  The fact that neither do suggests they don't think they could sell enough seats to make money on the route, as there are unlikely to be regulatory hurdles that completely block this route.

Comment: Great answer and probably the correct one. A very quick glance at the tickets Le flights from Melbourne to CapeTown brings up a lot of results. Almost all of them have a leg that is operated by either Qatar or Eremites Airline. Both of which would fly to or from their hub first. Since there is not an airline that has a continuous route, I would suspect that there is not one single airline that currently finds a direct route profitable. Airlines are businesses after all. They find it more feasible to use a hub and spoke roughing method.

Comment: Sorry to say that just because the original poster and a handful of other people may want a direct route, that small number does not justify the airlines maintaining a direct route.

Comment: This answer is correct, but just a note that [there are direct flights between Australia and South Africa](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/QFA63), even during the current pandemic. But apparently the airlines feel that they can profitably operate flights between the large cities SYD-JNB, but not MEL-CPT, and something like MEL-SYD-JNB-CPT may be more hassle than a one-stop journey with a change of planes at a hub like Doha or Hong Kong.

Comment: @mlc not surprising really as Johannesburg's area population is twice Cape Town's.  Although Sydney is only a little bigger than Melbourne its airport looks like it should serve a much larger population - anywhere from Canberra to Newcastle (at least)

Comment: I meant routing method, not roughing method. A similar situation exists or existed (have not been to South Africa in a couple of  years) when flying from Texas. It was easier to fly from Houston than from Dallas. And, much easier to fly from Dallas to Chicago, then to Joburg. But, it was cheaper to fly from Lanseria to Cape Town than from OR Tambo.

Comment: Silly fun fact: Some people say this proves the Earth is flat. The north pole is in the middle of the disc, and Antarctica is all around the outside edge, so the shortest paths between places in the southern hemisphere usually go via the northern hemisphere...

Comment: @user253751 - and on such a map the distance from Auckland to Sydney is the same as London to New York. Which given the flight time of 3 hours means that it's the best value flight in the world: a trans-Tasman Concorde for just a few hundred bucks. Why all the other Airbus + Boeing operators don't exploit the supersonic capabilities of their airliners is quite the puzzle...

Comment: @TomGoodfellow because it would reveal the earth is flat, duh

Comment: @TomGoodfellow Who is to say that the extra distance is not entirely over water? Australia might still have the size the map tells you. (I'm not endorsing this hypothesis, just pointing out that your argument is not a valid counter for it... ;) )

Comment: @I'mwithMonica - but as James Cook and his sextant can tell you that FE map does have Australia and NZ on the right longitudes, so it can only be that the Tasman Sea is as wide as the North Atlantic. Even worse is that the drive from Sydney to Perth is roughly the same as London to Beijing - that Australian drivers haven't remarked upon the excessive mileage speaks very poorly for the quality of Holden odometers.

Answer (score 10):

There is already a very good and accepted answer, so mine is just for added fun.

A very interesting way to visualize this is [www.flightconnections.com](http://www.flightconnections.com). It's an interactive map that shows all regularly scheduled direct flights. If you click on Capetown, you can see that nothing goes to Australia and the farthest west you can get is Hong Kong.

Now why is that?

Almost all airlines operate a **"hub and spoke"** system. That means their is one (or a few) "central" airport that's home to the airline and that serves individual flights to all other destinations. So almost all routes from A B to will have a layover at a hub, so you fly A->Hub->B (unless A or B are a Hub itself). The reason for that is easy: it allows the airline to serve a large numbers of city combination with relatively small number of direct flights. If you want to serve 100 cities with all possible combinations you would need 4950 different flights. With a hub and spoke system you only need 99. The hub also allows the airline to put all infrastructure in a single location since every plane shows up at the hub after every second flight.

Going back to your specific example. Neither Capetown nor Melbourne are hubs, so you would need an airline that has a different hub and serves both airports. Again, flightconnections.com can easily illustrate that if you put in both airports. Turns out the only airlines that do this are Emirates (Dubai), Qatar (Doha) and Cathay Pacific (Hong Kong). So these are your only choices with a single layover.

It tends to be easier if you use a hub "in region", but unfortunately South African (Johannesburg) doesn't serve Melbourne and Qantas (Sydney) doesn't serve Cape Town.

Side note: Looking at the map also explains why some relatively small middle eastern countries have massively large airlines (Emirates, Qatar, Etihad, ..) It's basic geography: with a hub in the middle east, you can connect all continents and the vast majority of the major cities in the world with a single layover. Emirates for example only operates the largest planes: Boeing 777 and Airbus A380. Only a tiny fraction of their passengers are actually traveling from/to Dubai.

Comment: If your drive to a hub airport is not much longer than to your nearest airport, it is sensible to drive that bit further. In South Africa the distances may be too big though.

Comment: FWIW, it does show me a flight from Sydney to Johannesburg

Comment: And my God, that site is full of ads. Including popups when you click on the map. Not a very nice site to explore.

Comment: @user253751: Qantas flies JNB<->SYD.  That doesn't help much with CPT<->MLE since it would be at least two layovers and the segments in South Africa would have to be on Qantas code share partnet (One World).

Comment: @Hilmar Yeah, but I thought it was noteworthy that there are direct flights between Australia and South Africa, just not between those particular two cities.

Comment: @Hilmar Also there's nothing wrong with taking an extra layover to save several hours of flying.

Comment: @user253751: Layover where? The only itineraries I can find  (Feb/Mar) are either with Qatar through Doha, with Singapore through JNB/SIN or with Kenya/Etihad through Nairobi and Abu Dabhi. None of these are pretty. You can always buy seperate tickets, but that's very risky and you need budget a lot more time for the layovers.

Comment: @Hilmar this [direct flight](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/QFA63) between Sydney and  Johannesburg happened 2 days ago.   The OP could have flown MEL->SYD->JNB->CPT and still been there before a flight going via Asia or the Middle East.

Comment: Not on a single ticket.

Answer (score -3):

The economics of hub and spoke matter, but also the distance over open ocean matters. For the entire route from Melbourne to Doha to Cape Town there are other airports to land at in the event of an emergency. But for a direct flight from Australia to Cape Town there's nothing. There's only one uninhabited mountainous island with no airport.  Shipping traffic doesn’t even go through there. It is very isolated. If a flight over that part of the world needs to come down it will have to ditch and rescuers will take weeks to arrive.

Comment: Except that direct flights between Johannesburg and Sydney do exist [and this one happened just 2 days ago](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/QFA63)

Comment: ETOPS certificate applies to airplanes and crews for long flights over areas without suitable airports. (Engines Turn Or Passengers Swim or google it formal meaning :-) ). The longest twin-engine plane diversion is allowed by ETOPS-240 i.e. diversion time should not exceed 4 hours on a single engine to the nearest suitable airport. Which could be a military base with a hangar in the snowy North. 4-engines don't need ETOPS but they go extinct for financial reasons.

Comment: This is completely wrong.  It's completely commonplace to have very long flights over water.  Note that cape town - Hong Kong is LONGER than CT - Melb, and is entirely water.

Comment: CT .. new york or atlanta is even longer, all water

Comment: @Fattie while those flights are mostly over water, there is still some land with airports somewhat nearby (reachable in an hour or such). That might be less of the case for the south indian ocean?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann , honestly, it's an absolute non issue.  I urge you to ask on the excellent "aviation" SE site if you like.  Note that of all international flights *by far* the most are ... across the atlantic, which is 10000%$ water.  The 1st sentence of this answer is utterly incorrect.  Check on "aviation SE" if you like!

Answer (score -3):

The question is a bit nonsensical.

The answer to "Why do you have to go through another airport" is simply **"there's no direct flight."**

If there's no direct flight between two cities ............... you have to go through another city.

When you want to fly to (say) Cape Town, **the first thing you do is simply bring up a map of all the direct flights** of Cape Town:

[image]

As you can instantly see your easiest choices are HK, Dubai or Doha.

Comment: This is at best half an answer, the information in it is (mostly) already in the other answers.